# Export region polygon from openstreet map

Tags: openstreetmap

Could someone inform whether it is possible to export the region Loddon Mallee from openstreetmap to geojson format?

http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/4246154#map=7/-35.791/143.064

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one quick way is to use Overpass Turbo

Go to https://overpass-turbo.eu/

Replace the code with the following and click "Run", if it warns you about the size click "continue anyway".

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
{{geocodeArea:Australia}}->.searchArea;
(
  relation["name"="Loddon Mallee"](area.searchArea);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Once it displays on the map, click "Export", then "GeoJSON" and the GeoJSON will download. You can also send it directly to a Gist https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4e79bd7cd9266b04c2151ea56ec3518d

To generate the query code yourself, click the "Wizard" option and then enter `name='Loddon Mallee' in Australia` in the Wizard box. I've optimized the query above to remove the node and way searches since I knew we were just looking for a relation. You can also leave off the "in Australia" part and just zoom the map manually over the correct region before running the query.